# Efficient way to select items < value from sorted array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, select

I have an array with sorted numbers, eg.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is there a way to select items < 5, without traversing the whole array?
Eg. the following will traverse the whole array and check each item. But, for a sorted array, it could break as soon as it hits an item >= 5.

```
arr.select { |p| p < 5 }
```

I've tried variations with break, next and return without success.

```
arr.select { |p| p < 5; break  if p >= 5 } # = nil
arr.select { |p| p < 5; next   if p >= 5 } # = []
arr.select { |p| p < 5; return if p >= 5 } # LocalJumpError
```

What's a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the [take_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-take_while) method for that.

Comment: Select is a bad way to do this.  If you break out of it before it finishes, it won't return the result you want.  Agree with baron816 on this.  take_while does exactly what you want.

Comment: Aren't you going to add `arr.take_while { |e| e < 5 }`?

Comment: Thanks, take_while is what I was looking for and works perfectly.

Comment: @BasselSamman `[1,2,3,4].select { |e| e.odd?.tap { break if e > 2 } } #⇒ [1]`.

Comment: Hahaha @mudasobwa true.  Nice trick, but using.odd? ends up giving you the wrong answer since it will skip even numbers.  Cool idea though, you can do [1,2,3,4].select { |e| e.tap { break if e > 2 } } or even [1,2,3,4].select { |e| true.tap { break if e > 2 } }  as long as the object doesn't evaluate to nil or false.  At the end of the day though still not as clean as the take_while.

Comment: @BasselSamman `take_while` is way more clean, indeed. I have just noted that escaping `select` is possible. Frankly, I did not get why you think that using `odd?` gives wrong result. I wanted to select odds and I ended up having them selected, with additional loop termination condition.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought you were giving an example of solving the same problem.  Didn't realize you were going for odds.  Either way, nice touch.  Way to tap dat object :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: `break` exits from the block. In this case, it exits from the block passed to `tap`, not the one passed to `select`, because that's the block you put the `break` in. In other words: your solution *does* iterate the entire array, returning `true` for odd elements less than 4, `false` for even elements less than 4 and `nil` for elements greater than or equal to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```
  > arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  > index = arr.index(5)
  #=> 4
  > arr[0..index]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Would work in this example, in my real data the value may not exist - so finding by index would not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, why did your solutions not work? `select` accepts a block, and it throws away all elements for which the block returns a false-ish value (`nil` or `false`) and keeps all the ones for which the block returns a true-ish value.

```
arr.select { |p| p < 5; break  if p >= 5 } # = nil
```

Here, you call `p < 5` but then you just ignore its return value. In Ruby, the return value of a block is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the block. The last expression evaluated here is `break if p >= 5`. Since there is no `else` case, it will return `nil` (which is `false`, i.e. means "do not keep this element") for all elements less than 5, and then it will `break` (which means "abort and return `nil`").

IOW: you are telling `select` to throw away all elements less than 5 and then to abort.

```
arr.select { |p| p < 5; next   if p >= 5 } # = []
```

In this case, again, you are returning `nil` for all elements less than 5, and for all elements greater than or equal to 5, you are returning the argument to `next` … but there is no argument, ergo, you are also returning `nil` for all elements greater than 5.

IOW: you are telling `select` to throw away all elements less than 5 and then you tell it to throw away all elements greater than or equal to 5, or, put another way, you tell it to throw away all elements … *and* you are still iterating the entire array.

This doesn't make much sense anyway. `next` is implied in a block, just like `return` is implied in a method. (In fact, `next` is for blocks what `return` is for methods), so all you have done is add a superfluous keyword.

```
arr.select { |p| p < 5; return if p >= 5 } # LocalJumpError
```

Again, the same as before … you are telling `select` to throw away all elements less than 5, and then you are `return`ing from the enclosing method. But there *is no* enclosing method, so Ruby `raise`s a `LocalJumpError`.

You could "fix" your second solution this way:

```
arr.select { |p| if p < 5 then true else next end }
```

I.e. you need to actually return `true` (or something true-ish) for elements less than 5. But, like I said, `next` is implied anyway, so you can just leave it out, which means this is equivalent to

```
arr.select { |p| if p < 5 then true else nil end }
```

Which, since `select` treats `false` and `nil` the same is equivalent to

```
arr.select { |p| if p < 5 then true else false end }
```

Which is of course just the same as

```
arr.select { |p| p < 5 }
```

Which, because of the symmetry of `<` and `>` is just the same as

```
arr.select(&5.method(:>))
```

Anyway, the correct solution for searching in a sorted array would be to use a binary search, which will not need to iterate the array *at all*, and will only need O(log(n)) comparisons:

```
arr.bsearch_index(&5.method(:<=))
```

This will search for the "index of the element at the next biggest index right of the last number that is less than 5". Then you can use [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) to extract the slice of elements you want

```
arr[0...arr.bsearch_index(&5.method(:<=))]
```

Note that `Array#bsearch_index` is [new in 2.3.0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/50839), I believe, until then, you can use [`Range#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Range.html#method-i-bsearch) [instead](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10730#note-1):

```
arr[0...(0...arr.size).bsearch {|i| arr[i] >= 5 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that using [Enumerable#lazy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) with [Enumerable#slice_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
arr.lazy.slice_before { |i| i >= 5 }.first
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

By making `slice_before` lazy, `first` terminates the slicing after the first slice is obtained.